# Trying to get element by className doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript

Trying to inject a dynamic year into HTML code.

Works fine with getElementById but getElementsByClassName doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code...

HTML

```
<p>this year is <span class="year"></span></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementsByClassName("year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Interested to see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("year")[0]`, because it's an array, you need to select the first one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get an array of elements with this method. To access the first element write this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("year")[0].innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object.

You can access each element in the collection with the same syntax as an array :

```
var yearCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("year");
yearCollection[0].innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

You can also use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to retrieve elements.

Using querySelector the result is more readable in my opinion :

```
document.querySelector(".year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` use CSS selectors to get element in the DOM.

For a quick perf comparison see : http://jsperf.com/selection-amdg2-azfne65

Comment: Thanks, I used querySelector and it's seemingly working perfectly. Once again thanks a lot.