# JavaScript getElementsByClassName error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a menu, but when I have tried to execute the code in Chrome I've got an error.

So for debug proposes I made a button:

```html
<input type="button" style="position: fixed; left:0; bottom:0; width:50px; height:25px;" value="test" onclick="login('logf')" />
```

This is the function where error is:

```
var loginshow = false;


function login(c)
{
    e = document.getElementsByClassName(c);
    if(loginshow)
    {
        e.style.height = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        e.style.height = "110px";
    }
    loginshow=!loginshow;

}
```

The error from google chrome:

```
bar.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined
    at login (bar.js:13)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):32)
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Comment: Which tool do you use to develope your application ? If you wish you can type debugger; just before your javascript code and when you browse your application, on the google chrome, you can press the key F12 to open the source view and debug your code. The code debugger; will be hit. And you can see, may be there is an error with the class name etc..

Comment: @Weedoze is correct, `e` is an array, so you need to iterate over the array of elements, or if you know there is only one, refer to it as `e[0].style.height`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Trying to get element by className doesn't seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28631930)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. You need to iterate all the elements and apply the style on each one

```js
var loginshow = false;


function login(c) {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(c);
  for(let i=0,l=elements.length;i<l;i++){
    elements[i].style.height = loginshow ? "0" : "110px";
  }
  loginshow = !loginshow;

}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" style="position: fixed; left:0; bottom:0; width:50px; height:25px;" value="test" onclick="login('logf')" />

<div class="logf"></div>
<div class="logf"></div>
```

Comment: It is not an Array, it is a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: @epascarello Answer updated, thanks !

Comment: Thank you, this post helped me with a few things